# Passing values into a templated object

Tags: c++

I'm re-creating the vector class with arrays, and am having a small error on passing in values to the object I create to test to see if the functions are working properly

Here is the code

```
template<typename T>
class stack
{
public:
void pop()
    {
        S1.pop_back();
    }
void push(T &e)
    {
        S1.push_back(e); 
    }
T& top()
    {
        counter = S1.Counter();
        cout << counter;
        return S1[counter];
    }
bool empty()
    {
        if (S1.Counter() == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
private:
sean<T> S1;
int counter;
};
```

Object call

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
stack<int> S1;
S1.push(1);


return 0;
}
```

In the main function I am just creating a "stack" object S1 and want to call the push(T&e) function but I am getting the error

```
Initial value of reference to non-const must be an Ivalue
```

It's probably something simple, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In the error message, that's probably an "lvalue", not "Ivalue". .... I mean, `lvalue` not `Ivalue` :D

Comment: I wish we had unique tags for specific homework questions, so that everyone who's trying to meet the "implement a Stack" deadline this weekend can band together.

Comment: @KerrekSB [Homework overflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44531/stack-overflow-homework)?

Comment: @DyP: Awesome, +1ed :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass a temporary but a normal reference can only bind variables.
This will solve the problem:

```
void push(T const& e)
{
        S1.push_back(e); 
}
```

Comment: "can only bind variables" non-const (lvalue-)references can bind to also bind to lvalues that are not variables. E.g. `int& foo(); int& ref = foo();` or `int& ref = *(new int);` (never do the latter, but it's possible). Variables are lvalues, so non-const lvalue-references can *also* bind to variables.